# JQuery function not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

This should be super simple. The first code block works, but when I wrap it in a function and attempt to call the function, it doesn't work.

**This Works:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $("#groups-image").hide();
        $("#quiz-image").hide();
        $("#members-image").hide();     

});
```

**This Doesn't Work:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        function hideatstart() {

        $("#groups-image").hide();
        $("#quiz-image").hide();
        $("#members-image").hide();     
        }

        hideatstart();
});
```

**UPDATE:** After looking at the accepted answer, I was able to get working code. It involved not having any spaces between the lines of code, which would allow p tags to be inserted. Best practice would be to remove the JQuery to a separate script, which I will do. The following code works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function hideatstart(){
        $("#groups-image").hide();
        $("#quiz-image").hide();
        $("#members-image").hide();
        }
    hideatstart();
});
```

Comment: It [seems to work for me](http://jsfiddle.net/EVhuw/)

Comment: agree with @JamesAllardice.  it seems to work correctly:  http://jsfiddle.net/nickadeemus2002/tB8m2/2/

Comment: Why on earth would you want to declare that function within the .ready function scope? if you do so at least call it by this.hideatstart() but for an anonymous function its a useless waste of space.

Comment: The latter code example definitely does not work. You can see it in action at http://righthampshire.com/. I'll post the full code for reference.

Comment: Hmm, your real website has `<p>` tags **inside** the `<script>` tag... `(function() {</p>` won't work indeed.

Comment: Note that the problem is entirely a WordPress issue, not a JS issue. From what you've shown, I don't see why WordPress didn't insert `<p>` tags in your first version too.

Comment: @nnnnnn Agreed. That's why I edited the tags to include "wordpress." This was a sincere question, which has been answered, and I don't believe this post deserves the -6 rating it initially received based on the pre-updated version. A few +1 votes would be appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately some people are very quick to down-vote, often without explanation. Sometimes 100% correct answers get down-voted. I've learnt to just ignore it - try not to take it personally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I inspected the HTML on your live site and found that your snippet is outputted like this:

```
<div class="art-postcontent">
    <!-- article-content -->
    <!-- [snipped] -->
    <p><script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script><br />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {</p>
<p>         function hideatstart() {</p>
<p>         $("#groups-image").hide();
            $("#quiz-image").hide();
            $("#members-image").hide();     
            }</p>
<p>         hideatstart();
    });
</script></p>
    <!-- [snipped] -->
</div>
```

As you can see, WordPress's `wpautop` filter wrapped your lines inside paragraphs.

If you need to inject a script somewhere, you better do it with a plugin or a theme function and *not* by pasting the code in a WordPress post or widget. All regular WordPress content types are escaped to prevent such possibly malicious injections. It seems like you're using a custom `art` post type, which normally gets a similar treatment. There are ways to prevent the content from being escaped, but you should **seriously** consider moving your script code somewhere else.

Comment: I appreciate the answer. I actually think this is going to solve a number of outstanding questions I have concerning JQuery and Ajax in Wordpress. Moving the JS code to a separate file may prove to be the right answer in those cases. I plan on linking back to this question once I determine if that was the issue in the other cases. I have no idea why this got a -6 rating, but I suspect it has something to do with other users not evaluating the HTML output and thinking there wasn't a problem. Any +1 votes would be appreciated.